# SQL in Access to add leading 0 in front of zip codes

Tags: ms-access, csv, string-manipulation, number-formatting

for a project I am working with a table of zip-codes that I imported from a *.csv file, exported form Excel. Those zipcodes all have 5 numbers and are formatted as text within my database. Some of them should start with 0, however during the export/import process this 0 got lost, leaving me with zip-codes that only have 4 instead of 5 digits where the leading 0 went missing.

Is there a way an SQL command might add this zero to strings only having 4 digits?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you're storing Zip codes in a *numeric* Data Type.

No problem.  This should do the trick:

```
select 
  format( zipcode, '00000' ) as zipcode_fmt 
from ...
```

Of course, if you want the leading zeroes to be in the field permanently, they you need to change the Data Type.  Numbers don't have leading zeroes, but the *String Representation* of those numbers *can*.  In most DBMSs, you'd add a new field, varchar(5), update that field with the format'ted values, as above, then drop the original field and replace it with the new one.
In "Dear Little Access", though, you'll probably have to create a whole new *table*, with the new field, insert the formatted data into it, drop the original table and replace it with the new one.